# React/Redux simple table throwing data.map is not a function TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a simple React table initiation which creates a TypeError: data.map is not a function. The table renders if i pass a simple Array into it (like [1,2,3]) instead of the certData variable which is an object.

I would like to render a table that has all distinct "Full Name"s from both cert and non_cert arrays in the left hand column and a list of "Alias"s who have them in the right hand column. So it would look like:

```
123 | ABC, DEC

789 | GHI
```

Here is the code i have right now

```
const TeamExpertiseTable = (props) => {
  const certData = props.teamCerts;
  console.log(certData);

  const columns = () => {
      return [
        {
          header: 'Certification Name',
          accessor: 'Cert Name'
        },
        {
          header: 'Team Members',
          accessor: 'Alias'
        }
      ]
  }

    return (
        <div>
            <Table
                activeSortID="Cert Name"
                columns={columns()}
                data= {certData}
                isStriped={true}
                shouldAutoCollapseOnExpand={false}
                sortDirection="ascending"
                spacing="default"
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

where the certData object is as follows:

```
{
    "Count": 79,
    "cert": [
        {
            "Full Name": "ABC",
            "Alias": "ABC",
            "Cert Type": "ABC",
            "Cert Name": "123"
        },
                {
            "Full Name": "DEF",
            "Alias": "ABC",
            "Cert Type": "ABC",
            "Cert Name": "123"
        }
    ],
    [
     "non_cert": [
        {
            "Full Name": "GHI",
            "Alias": "ABC",
            "Cert Type": "ABC",
            "Cert Name": "789"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you looping over `cert` & `non-cert` ? Because they have array of objects and we can iterate over them using map method.

Comment: May you share the component code which is throwing the error? I'm also confused why this is tagged with redux when there's no redux code?

Comment: it seems that props.teamCerts is an object, not an array

Comment: Where is teamCerts in certData?

Answer (score 0):

The certData is an object, while the Table component expects an array, which contains a map method in its prototype. You can pass certData.cert or certData['cert']

Comment: if i use certData.cert or certData['cert'] i get the same error...

Comment: maybe try ```certData.cert || [] ```, so that in case you don't have any data at a given moment the app doesn't crash

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass it an array and `certData` is an object in your case.

You should pass `certData.cert` or `certData.non_cert`:

```
return (
        <div>
            <Table
                activeSortID="Cert Name"
                columns={columns()}
                data= {certData.cert}
                isStriped={true}
                shouldAutoCollapseOnExpand={false}
                sortDirection="ascending"
                spacing="default"
            />
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: if i use certData.cert or certData['cert'] i get the same error...

Answer (score 0):

I assuming that you are looping over the `cert` property, in that case you will need to initialize `teamCerts` with an empty array or:

```
const certData = props.teamCerts.cert || [];
```

Comment: Check that teamCerts is not an object

Comment: It should be an array to use map

Comment: I dont want to use map specifically, i just passed the data into the data attribute of the table component. Is there a way around using map implicitly?

Comment: What data do you want to pass to Table component: cert or non_cert?

Comment: Ideally i want to have Distinct Cert Names from both cert and non_cert as each row and then a list of all the Aliases that have that Cert Name in the cell to the right of it. So an array of Cert Names in column  index 0 and an Array or Arrays in column in 1. Does that make sense?

Comment: In that case you will need to transform the data in that format before render it. What format do you have in mind?

Comment: I would like the rows to be like this Cert Name | Cert Type | alias 1, alias 2, alias 3

Comment: I recommend you update your question according to what you receive and expect to show in the component

Comment: I didnt realise i could edit it- i created a new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66753679/how-to-build-a-react-table-using-object-instead-of-array-as-data

Answer (score 0):

The certData is object, not Array value.

Please try this.

```
            <Table
                activeSortID="Cert Name"
                columns={columns()}
                data= {certData.cert}
                isStriped={true}
                shouldAutoCollapseOnExpand={false}
                sortDirection="ascending"
                spacing="default"
            />
```

And if you want cert and non cert data

```
let dataArray = [];
dataArray.push(certData.cert)
dataArray.push(certData.non_cert)
          
...

            <Table
                activeSortID="Cert Name"
                columns={columns()}
                data= {dataArray}
                isStriped={true}
                shouldAutoCollapseOnExpand={false}
                sortDirection="ascending"
                spacing="default"
            />
```

Comment: This gives me a new error:

Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {Full Name, Alias, Cert Type, Cert Name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: When you use type script, you have to define object types. I will add new post for this.

Answer (score 0):

When you use type script you have to define about the object or array

```
type Cert = {
   "Full Name"?: string,
   "Alias"?: string,
   "Cert Type"?: string,
   "Cert Name"?: string
}
```

After that you can get the data with this type.

```
const ChildComponent = ({data}:Cert[]) = >{
   data.map((item, key)=>(
      <React.Fragment key={key}>
          {item.Full Name}
      </React.Fragment>

   ))
}
```

If there is any error, please let me know.