# How to build a React Table using Object instead of Array as data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple React table initiation which creates a TypeError: data.map is not a function. The table renders if i pass a simple Array into it (like [1,2,3]) instead of the certData variable which is an object.

I would like to render a table that has all distinct "Full Name"s from both cert and non_cert arrays in the left hand column and a list of "Alias"s who have them in the right hand column. So it would look like:

```
123 | ABC, DEC

789 | GHI
```

Here is the code i have right now

```
const TeamExpertiseTable = (props) => {
  const certData = props.teamCerts;
  console.log(certData);

  const columns = () => {
      return [
        {
          header: 'Certification Name',
          accessor: 'Cert Name'
        },
        {
          header: 'Team Members',
          accessor: 'Alias'
        }
      ]
  }

    return (
        <div>
            <Table
                activeSortID="Cert Name"
                columns={columns()}
                data= {certData}
                isStriped={true}
                shouldAutoCollapseOnExpand={false}
                sortDirection="ascending"
                spacing="default"
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

where the certData object is as follows:

```
{
    "Count": 79,
    "cert": [
        {
            "Full Name": "ABC",
            "Alias": "ABC",
            "Cert Type": "ABC",
            "Cert Name": "123"
        },
                {
            "Full Name": "DEF",
            "Alias": "ABC",
            "Cert Type": "ABC",
            "Cert Name": "123"
        }
    ],
    [
     "non_cert": [
        {
            "Full Name": "GHI",
            "Alias": "ABC",
            "Cert Type": "ABC",
            "Cert Name": "789"
        }
    ]
}
```